# Map API JSON fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I have problems when putting the data of a Laravel API in React, when doing the fetch and bringing the data, the JSON data appears in the console without problems, but when I want to put them in a table to list them, an error appears and says that my `.map` is not a function, I hope you can help me.

```
import React from 'react';

class Crudcategories extends React.Component{

    state = {
        categories:[]
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/categories")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(categoriesJson => this.setState({categories:categoriesJson}))
    }
    
    render(){
        const{categories} =this.state
        
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Categories</h1>

                <br/>
                <table className="table table-striped table-border table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {categories.map((category,i)=>
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <th scope="row">{i+1}</th>
                                <td>{category.name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Crudcategories
```

I have tried to change my fetch, my map, but I can't solve it

Comment: Please note that the main Stackoverflow site is English-only. Either edit your post to be in English, or head on over to https://es.stackoverflow.com for the Spanish-only version of Stackoverflow. Having said that, whether you keep the post here or post it on the Spanish site: [do not post images of text](/help/how-to-ask). Post the text. With appropriate [markdown](/markdown).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using .map() on a JSON object, which won't work, as objects do not have a .map() function.

Try converting your JSON data to an array of objects then try .map()

Example:

```
const categoriasArr = Object.values(categorias).map(value => value);
```

Then use categoriasArr.map()